# How to change the class of an object without creating a new one?

Tags: java

Say I have a class Foo, and two classes Foo1 and Foo2 extending Foo.

Say I have a Foo f, which turns out to be a Foo1 , and I want to change it without using a constructor. If it was just a matter of changing the fields of f, I could do it manually:

```
f.field1= ..
f.field2= ..
```

But what can I do if I want to change it into a Foo2 ?

N.B : The point is that I would like to do something like that :

```
Foo f=new Foo1( ...);
Foo g=f;
g=new Foo2(...);
```

and have f change when g changes, but obviously this does not work.

Comment: You can't change what things are in Java. You can only make different things.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to elaborate? If you do Foo1 f1 = new Foo1(); Foo g=f1; and then something like g.setSomething("val") - this changes both g and f1. I'm not sure why you have g = new Foo2() there and what do you mean by "have f change when g changes" in this case.

Comment: I would like f and g to become a Foo2, which can not be achieved by g.setSomething("...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something around those lines. Note: this code is pseudo-code.

```
abstract class Common{
...
}

class Foo{
  private Common currentReference;

  public Foo(...){
    currentReference = new Foo1();
  }

  public Foo changeReferenceToClass(Class clazz){
    ...
    currentReference = clazz.newInstance();
    ...
    return this;
  }

  public <T extends Common> T getReference()
  {
    return (T) currentReference;
  }
}

class Foo1 extends Common{
...
}

class Foo2 extends Common{
...
}

Foo f=new Foo( ... );
Foo g=f;
g=g.changeReferenceToClass(Foo2.class);
```

What this does is:

- make an class that contains a reference to an object that has a `common` interface (in the example, the `Common` abstract class.
- instantiate the reference to a default value when it is constructed (`Foo1` in the example).
- offer methods to `change` and `get` the reference.
- when you change the reference to be Foo2 in one place, you can access it in all places

In the example, when you change `g` to hold a reference to `Foo2`, `f` will hold a reference to `Foo2` too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Java is [static typed programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking) and [strong typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), so unless `Foo2` is a subclass of `Foo`, it won't work. But even doing this, you only change the type of the object reference of the variable (and enabling polymorphism), not the type of the variable.

Comment: I doubt that the reason for that is that Java is statically typed. It could be dynamically typed and you could still not be able to change the class of a an object. The type system is something that works at runtime, the compiler just helps to follow the rules of the type system.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I forgot to add that Java is strong typed also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Java because the type you declare it as is the type you are limited to. That's how static typing works. That said you can do this:

```
Foo g = new Foo2();
((Foo2)g).gInstanceMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained why you can't change the class of an existing object. But even if you could, what you're trying to do wouldn't work because of the way Java's references work.

```
 Foo f=new Foo1( ...);
```

This line allocates a new object on the heap, calls the `Foo1` constructor to initialize it, and stores a *reference* to that object in the variable `f`.

```
 Foo g=f;
```

This line *copies* the *value* of the reference (i.e. copies the address, not the object being referenced) to a new variable `g`.

```
 g=new Foo2(...);
```

This line allocates a new object on the heap, calls the `Foo2` constructor to initialize it, and stores a *reference* to the new object into `g`, overwriting the reference that was previously stored there. The object previously referred to by `g` is never affected by this operation.